# Do not evaluate right side expression if left side expression is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am writing some component in my iOS app. If user has selected to turn off this feature I am returning nil from my functions.

```
//self.currentRequest would be nil if user has turned off the feature.
     self.currentRequest.startTimeStamp = [NSDate date];
        self.currentRequest.url = [request.URL absoluteString];
```

I want that right side expression should not evaluate if left side expression is nil.
I don't want to wrap the code using `if-else`, because code is spread over the functions to record timings.
I read Swift documentation, looks like Swift has `if let` syntax to do that. How this can be done in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this? but if startTimeStamp is a readonly, this will not work.

```
self.currentRequest.startTimeStamp = self.currentRequest.startTimeStamp ? [NSDate date] : nil;
```

Although, your best bet here is probably just an if-case. Why don't you want to use it?

```
if(self.currentRequest)
{
   //Do your stuff....
}
```

---

Perhaps this? (If inside a void-function)

```
if(!self.currentRequest) return;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I am not interested in if-else blocks. Since I have written code to record timings in many functions. I don't want to put if-else on all the locations.

Comment: But why do you need an else-block? You dont, just wrap it in an if-block if you don't want to do stuff if it's nil. You are suggesting an "if let"-equivalent. There's no such thing in objc, just use a simple if. Also, what about my last suggestion with the return?

Comment: I cant return nil since function is doing other stuff, I just inserted bunch of statements at the beginning and end of function to record time that function took to execute in-between statements. self.current request comes from my utility class and used all over the place where I need to log the timings.

Comment: You do not want to edit it to a `if` block, but you are searching for something like `if let`, which you would edit it to!?